# Need help troubleshooting live paint, shape builder tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, cmyk

I have packaging that is created with lines (paths). I need to color some of the parts of the packaging. I am having difficulty using various tools to create a shape from my paths (shape builder, pathfinder and live paint bucket). I managed to come close (I think) using live paint bucket, but when I go to apply a color, the only option I have is "k". There is no "c", "m" or "y".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your current selection has a black stroke and no fill. I suspect the stroke is in Greyscale mode.

Select your fill, select a color, go to the color window, use the dropdown arrow in top right and make sure color setting is CMYK.

Before applying the paintbucket I load up the fill and stroke I need, select the objects and then apply paintbucket.

With your color selected in the fill and in CMYK color mode apply the paintbucket. (Do you really want a stroke on your paint objects? if not turn it off and have only a fill)

Comment: How do I make a shape from the paths that I selected? And still keep the fold marks (dotted line)?

Answer (score 0):

Live Paint just applies **swatch colors** to areas.

You can use the arrow keys (<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>) to "walk" through the swatches in the Swatch Panel. You should see the little 3-box cursor change colors as you do. The middle color is the one which will be applied. The left and right boxes indicate the adjacent swatch colors.

[image]

Or you can simply click a swatch you want to use, then click the object on the Artboard with the Live Paint Bucket Tool.